# Disable clearing of D3.js brush

Tags: javascript, user-interface, d3.js, brush

I would like to use a D3.js brush to allow users to select a range of values on an axis. By default, clicking outside the brush clears it, so that no range is selected.

However, I would like to adjust this behaviour so that clicking outside the brush doesn't alter the brush extent. In effect, there should be no way to clear the brush, some range should always be selected.

I believe I have to hook into the [`brush` event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_on) somehow to disable the clearing, but I don't really know how to go about that.

Here's an example of the kind of interface I'm talking about ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWjD8/)). When you click to the left or right of the black bar, the brush is cleared and the bar disappears.

[image]

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

d3 brush by design calls 'brushmove()' once a user presses a mouse on the brush element (i.e. on 'mousedown.brush' event).
If effectively leads to resetting the previous brush extent.

A possible workaround is to replace the original mousedown.brush handler with the custom one. The custom handler will only call the original handlers once the mouse was moved after initial mousedown.

```
var brushNode = chart.append("g")
    .call(brush);

brushNode
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("height", 10);

// store the reference to the original handler
var oldMousedown = brushNode.on('mousedown.brush');

// and replace it with our custom handler
brushNode.on('mousedown.brush', function () {
    brushNode.on('mouseup.brush', function () {
        clearHandlers();
    });

    brushNode.on('mousemove.brush', function () {
        clearHandlers();
        oldMousedown.call(this);
        brushNode.on('mousemove.brush').call(this);
    });

    function clearHandlers() {
        brushNode.on('mousemove.brush', null);
        brushNode.on('mouseup.brush', null);
    }
})
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWjD8/1/).

Comment: I got the idea. But I wonder did you get an error like: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined " when you run this code, it seems that there is no mousemove.brush event handler binded to brushNode.

Comment: Hi @kuan, have you solved above issue? Is there any problem / side effects happened using above solution with error??

Comment: @Nithin CV Poyyil  No, this seems work in the example above, but not work in my case. The way I use is: remember the brush extent initially, and in brushend, if (!brush.empty()) {ext = brush.extent();}else { brush.extent(ext); } and set the brush and redraw the axis

Comment: how can I see if the move started on the selection?

Comment: @Kuan, you can get rid of that error by removing `brushNode.on('mousemove.brush').call(this);`

Comment: oh, I had to use a mouseOver to set a flag if the selection is being moved/adjusted, else, do nothing